# Java - Vaadin - Table not filling

Tags: java, json, vaadin

little bit of a pickle here. I am reading a JSON From a Zip file and I want to fill a table in Vaadin with the contents of the JSON.

Here's my Function to read the stuff and fill the table, this is Java.

```
private void getJsonContent() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(backupFile);
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
            ZipEntry entry;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while((entry = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                if(entry.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("content.json")) {
                    int n;
                    while((n = zin.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > -1){
                        String JSON = new String(buffer, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSON);

                        logger.info(JSON);

                        // Assign "global" Values to Variables
                        this.createdAt = obj.getString("created_at");
                        this.version = obj.getString("version");

                        // Fill table if applicable                     
                        for(int i = 0; i < obj.getJSONArray("content").length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject sub = obj.getJSONArray("content").getJSONObject(i);
                            logger.info(sub);

                            infoTable.addItem(new Object[] {
                                    sub.get("imported_identities").toString(),
                                    sub.get("project_versions").toString(),
                                    sub.get("last_import").toString(),
                                    sub.get("client").toString(),
                                    sub.get("project").toString()
                            }, i +1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            zin.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // Can't happen here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.info("Can't read File.");
        } catch (JSONException jse) {
            logger.info("JSON Content could not be read: " + jse.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

You will notice I have a function call `logger.info(sub)` - to make sure what I get is another valid JSON Object (the file I am reading contains nested things)

Output:

```
{"imported_identities":0,"project_versions":0,"last_import":null,"client":"Client1","project":"Project2"} 
{"imported_identities":0,"project_versions":0,"last_import":null,"client":"Client2","project":"Project1"}
{"imported_identities":0,"project_versions":1,"last_import":"2016-09-14T09:28:24.520Z","client":"Client1","project":"Project1"}
```

I made sure all the values were correct (and the table is built with null as default) - here is the table properties:

```
    infoTable.addContainerProperty(impIds, String.class, null);
    infoTable.addContainerProperty(projVe, String.class, null);
    infoTable.addContainerProperty(lstImp, String.class, null);
    infoTable.addContainerProperty(client, String.class, null);
    infoTable.addContainerProperty(projct, String.class, null);

    infoTable.setColumnCollapsingAllowed(true);
    infoTable.setColumnCollapsed(impIds, true);
    infoTable.setColumnCollapsed(projVe, true);
    infoTable.setColumnCollapsed(lstImp, true);
```

Finally, the table has "refreshRowCache" called on it. Anyone see the problem? There are no errors, no nothing, the table just doesn't add the item (the size of `infoTable.getItemIds().size()` is 0 right after the call.

EDIT:

I tried the following to verify.

```
infoTable.addItem(i + 1);
infoTable.getItem(i + 1).getItemProperty(impIds).setValue(sub.get("imported_identities").toString());
infoTable.getItem(i + 1).getItemProperty(projVe).setValue(sub.get("project_versions").toString());
```

This went and caused a NullPointerException, the stack trace however does not contain any of my classes as far as I can see.

Comment: As a first step I would set up a POJO class with members for each cell in a row. After you successfully filled a Java container with the POJOs that contain the data from JSON, you use a Container (e.g. BeanItemContainer) to bind that to the table. `table.setContainerDataSource(new BeanItemContainer<>(POJO.class, yourListOfPojos))`

Comment: Nevermind. Been up for too long. My table wasn't properly initialized before I tried to fill it, resulting in expectable nullpointers. The rest of the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is wrong:

1. The String constructor needs the read size (`n`).

   ```
               while ((n = zin.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > -1) {
                   String JSON = new String(buffer, 0, n, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   ```
2. Then you do JSONs of at most 1024 in the loop, instead on one JSON of it all
3. The bytes of a UTF-8 cannot be split at some point say at position 1024 and expect to have a valid complete multi-byte sequence at end and following block's begin.
4. Also there is `readFully` and `closeEntry` was missing.

In short:

```
private void getJsonContent() {
    try (ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(backupFile)))) {
        ZipEntry entry;
        while ((entry = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            if (entry.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("content.json")) {
                long size = entry.getSize();
                if (size > 100_000) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data too large");
                }
                // We could use an InputStreamReader and read text piecewise.
                // However JSON parsing also is easiest on an entire text.
                byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)size];
                int n = zin.readFully(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                String json = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
                logger.info(json);

                // Assign "global" Values to Variables
                this.createdAt = obj.getString("created_at");
                this.version = obj.getString("version");

                // Fill table if applicable                     
                for (int i = 0; i < obj.getJSONArray("content").length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject sub = obj.getJSONArray("content").getJSONObject(i);
                    logger.info(sub);

                    infoTable.addItem(new Object[] {
                            sub.get("imported_identities").toString(),
                            sub.get("project_versions").toString(),
                            sub.get("last_import").toString(),
                            sub.get("client").toString(),
                            sub.get("project").toString()
                    }, i + 1);
                }
            } // if
            zin.closeEntry(); // Do not forget preparing for the next entry
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.info("Can't read File.");
    } catch (JSONException jse) {
        logger.info("JSON Content could not be read: " + jse.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The try-with-resources closes automatically even on exception or return.

Comment: Look at above comments. Still thanks for giving me some ideas in Improving my code, I ran into the problem you described just before I came back to check here. (incomplete/corrupt byte sequence)

Comment: Thing I noticed, method "readFully" is not visible, I'm sticking with read() there